# Set different foreign key value in django inline formset initially

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset, django-inlinecss

I am trying to make a result management system using django. And for storing the subjects marks, I am using the django inline formset. The problem is that the user have to select a subject manually from dropdown which is Select Field in django and I think this will not be a good choice to do. So I decided to set the SelectField initially to those foreign field. But the initial value is always set to the last object of the Subject model.

```
def subject_mark_create(request, grade_pk, exam_pk):
    subjects =  Subject.objects.get_by_grade(grade_pk).order_by('name')
    SubjectMarkFormset = inlineformset_factory(Exam, SubjectMark,  extra=subjects.count(), max_num=subjects.count(), fk_name='exam', form=SubjectMarkForm, can_delete=False)
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        formset = SubjectMarkFormset(instance=exam)
        for form in formset:
            for subject in subjects:
                form['subject'].initial = subject
```

[My Current inlineformset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY36P.png)

[What I desired my formset should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfr65.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you to keep the initial value of subject field of form to a subject object

```
def subject_mark_create(request, grade_pk, exam_pk):
    subjects =  Subject.objects.get_by_grade(grade_pk).order_by('name')
    SubjectMarkFormset = inlineformset_factory(Exam, SubjectMark,  extra=subjects.count(), max_num=subjects.count(), fk_name='exam', form=SubjectMarkForm, can_delete=False)
    exam = get_object_or_404(Exam, pk=exam_pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        formset = SubjectMarkFormset(instance=exam)
        for index, form in enumerate(formset):
            form['subject'].initial = subjects[index]
```

Comment: No, I want each and every form field of subject to be unique.

Comment: In that case you must have number of subject objects more than or equal to forms you are trying to use. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much. I was really working hard for this solution since last 3 weeks and I really got the solution as I was expecting. A big Thanks to Danish Wani :)